# str_replace a NULL value

Tags: php

I'm trying to use str_replace to replace '' values to 'phone', I've used the code below but it isn't replacing anything:

```
<?php
$start_up = str_replace('','phone','start_up');
$sales = str_replace('','phone','');
$resourcing = str_replace('','phone','resourcing');
$management = str_replace('','phone','');
$array = "($start_up OR $sales OR $resourcing OR $management)";

echo $array;
?>
```

I want this to come up with:

```
(start_up OR phone OR resourcing OR phone)
```

But instead it is doing this:

```
(start_up OR OR resourcing OR )
```

I know I can use a !isset($var) type query but this seems clunky and long winded. Is there a way to include blank strings in a str_replace query?

Comment: `if empty($string)`

Comment: `str_replace('','phone','')` you search '' and replace it by 'phone' in ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`:

```
$start_up = preg_replace('/^$/','phone','start_up');
$sales = preg_replace('/^$/', 'phone', '');
$resourcing = preg_replace('/^$/','phone','resourcing');
$management = preg_replace('/^$/','phone','');
$array = "($start_up OR $sales OR $resourcing OR $management)";

echo $array;
```

Output:

```
(start_up OR phone OR resourcing OR phone)
```

and it will replace, an empty string with `phone`.

**Edit:** OR you can use `empty()` and [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$start_up = empty('start_up') ? 'phone' : 'start_up';
$sales = empty('') ? 'phone' : '';
$resourcing = empty('resourcing') ?'phone' : 'resourcing';
$management = empty('') ? 'phone' : '';
$array = "($start_up OR $sales OR $resourcing OR $management)";

echo $array;
```

Output same as above.

Comment: testing, that string is empty, is much less expensive than regex